# Passing the page ID to a login php script

Tags: php, pages, user-registration, id

I'm trying to create a simple registration process which goes like this,

1. A visitor clicks on a link (which is viewable only after entering
   some information such as name, email, phone etc.)
2. This link takes the visitor to a simple registration form that captures all
   the required info.
3. And on successful validation of the form redirects the visitor back to the actual URL.

To do this, first I thought of passing the actual URL as a variable to the php login script but then anybody can see this URL in the status bar of their browsers and would be able to bypass the registration process completely.

Now I believe another way to do this is to pass the actual ID of the destination URL as a variable to the login PHP script. Can anyone help me on how to actually go about this? The registration form can be a seperate PHP file that opens as a popup or can be a form thats embedded in one of the pages.